# Where should I be asking questions about public speaking?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I almost posted a note in interpersonal.SE about communication in public speaking, but it doesn't fit for the same reason many writing.SE questions don't naturally fit interpersonal.SE.

My question is as follows:

> In [Speak like a leader](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bGBamfWasNQ), Simon Lancaster says that lessons learned in Roman times about effective political speeches still apply, and it is scandalous that a training in rhetoric is such a rarity. He briefly touches six major lessons in effective speaking, but he does not flesh it out beyond what is permitted in a TED talk.
>
> What are the classic texts, ancient and modern, offering a foundational treatment of the rhetoric that furnishes his six highlights?

Where should I best ask this question?

Comment: One of them might be Cicero's speeches about Catilina. Had to read it in school and wasn't it fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are the classic texts, ancient and modern, offering a foundational treatment of the rhetoric that furnishes Simon Lancaster's six highlights mentioned in his TedX Talk: "Speak like a leader".

IPS does have the tags speaking and [public-speaking](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-speaking), you'd also need to be careful how you ask on [History.SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/12673/how-did-lay-people-understand-logic-in-the-greco-roman-world) - it's not *only* about the question you ask but what kind of answer you want. Indeed those don't seem correct for your question.

Our [Literature.SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) site seems closest to your requirements.

Be certain to list those six points in your question, so people don't have to watch the video.