# Site recommendation for asking presentation related questions

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope

I am an undergraduate student who is assigned with the tasks of implementing **presentations** for my project work. I need to know if there is a site on Stack Exchange to ask about the best practices (as in if *some particular ABC topic* could go in a better way if inserted prior to *some other XYZ topic*) in presentations or the organized manner of writing one. I am not asking for proofreading purposes (which is highly off-topic on ELL and ELU), I am asking about organization, designing and stuff.

Comment: Look at the [microsoft-powerpoint](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-powerpoint) tag on [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).  But please note that if it's too much like doing your homework, that won't slide.

Comment: I prefer using my own creativity and resources like google slides , it is a very good free tool!

Comment: @Ollie I am not asking about homework or anything such. I just want to know some things like, _should I include one topic before another one?_ or in that context. Like the ordering of the contents. Will it be okay to post such questions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- [microsoft-powerpoint](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-powerpoint) (https://superuser.com ) returns 1250 questions. But it's very likely that asking for best practices or the format of writing one will be off-topic. Anyway the tag excerpt doesn't help

  > Commercial software presentation program included in all editions of the Microsoft Office suite.
- [microsoft-powerpoint](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-powerpoint) (https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) returns 114 questions

  > Questions about the presentation software from Microsoft, based on a "slideshow" methodology.

Anyway, maybe you are giving too much emphasis on the tool while what you might be looking is techniques for *visual aids* for *public speaking*, but that might be too broad... and you should think on the purpose of your *presentation* (as a human act, rather than a *document*)

- [presentation](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presentation) (Academia) has 492 questions

  > Oral presentations: preparation of slides, preparation of the talk, delivery…
- [presentations](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presentations) (The Workplace) has only 42 questions, no tag excerpt.

Related

- [Where should I be asking questions about public speaking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343715/289691)

Comment: to be honest what the OP asks might be too broad and/or opinion bssed (*best practices*) you might want to warn for that as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for that line `maybe you are giving too much emphasis on the tool while what you might be looking is techniques for visual aids for public speaking`. Actually you are quite right. I edited my question. I am not looking for any particular software usage, it can be via any tool. I am looking more into _presentation of slides_.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh So good that I included two sites that might be appropiate for your questions.

Comment: @Rubén The Academia and Graphic Design site helped me. Thank you so much.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh Great! Thanks for sharing that.