# Can I ask (and where should I) a question about a public speaking manual I cannot find anymore?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am new to SE so please bear with me if this is not the right place for such a question. I have already looked and found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343715/where-should-i-be-asking-questions-about-public-speaking) but I do not think it is what I am looking for.
My question is, can I ask the below question (and where should I)?

> A couple of months ago I found a book (not the pdf; on an e-commerce
> site) regarding public speaking that I deemed very interesting. I was
> looking for something more or less directly applicable to
> politics/political speeches, and I came across this book (quite
> recent, published not many years ago really) by a French author. The
> book was also translated into Italian, which was actually the version
> I had found. Now, I have been looking for it in the past few days, but
> since the only things that I remember are the very few details above,
> I was not able to find it (or at least I did not recognize it among
> the one that I had found). I remember that the author was a man and
> the Italian translator probably a woman, but I am not 100% sure of
> this. I also remember that the cover had a white background (but it
> was not completely white). Honestly I really need only the name of the
> author, but I have no idea what else I can do. Does anyone know
> anything about such a book?

So basically I am looking for either the title of the book (does not matter the language) or the name of the author, but I do not have much information. Also, what tags should I add (depending on the site where I should post this)?

Comment: The question you want to ask appear to be an identification question. Those are  both loved and hated. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357529/which-se-sites-accept-identification-questions

Comment: Should remain open due to: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24050/181886 https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4281/26838 - or otherwise be closed for the *correct* duplicate, not yet suggested.

Comment: @gnat Hi, so you are suggesting such a question is not allowed? Because I saw many people looking for the titles/names of novels/tv series they had read/watch when they were younger.

Comment: @rene Hi, thanks for you answer. However, I do not see in the linked list any SE site related to my specific question. Do you think this is a "No"?

Comment: I will not call "No" but I wouldn't have high hopes either. It is weekend and MSE isn't that active. Give it some days for more eyes on it.

Comment: Did you try looking through the history of your browser? Chrome keeps track of visited pages for way longer then you hope for ...

Comment: Identification questions [are common on Stack Exchange site *Science Fiction & Fantasy*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/240251).